# argv and argc always give the NULL

Tags: php, argv, argc

I am using a shared server.
In my php.ini file :

```
register_argc_argv=On
```

when I use phpinfo() it shows:
[image]

but when i use var_dump($argc) & var_dump($argv) it shows always NULL. Don't know why.How to solve this please give suggestion .

Comment: what is there in `$argc` and `$argv`?

Comment: is it command line `Contains an array of all the arguments passed to the script when running from the command line. ` Turning these on  `register_argc_argv ` only turns them on for CLI,  `This variable is not available when register_argc_argv is disabled`.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Also there is often a separate INI file for command line,  `php-cli.ini` so even if you run it command line, with it on in the `php.ini` if you have a cli ini you may not have them on in the correct file.  Although I see this mostly on WAMP  servers, I cant honestly say if its same on Linux, as I dont mess with the Linux server ( our CSO does that one ).  In any case you should run phpinfo on the command line so it's in the correct environment.